# Excel If Statement (Auto Fill)

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, spreadsheet, auto-populate

How can I do an if statement based on criteria in multiple cells that auto fills a blank cell? I would like to auto populate a cell for example cell E7, based on the text in cell D7, the text in D7 could contain one of 7 different text.

Based on the text in D7 I would like E7 to auto populate one of 7 different prices from one of 7 different cells. The if statement =IF(isBlank($D7),"JP-5",$J$3) would work for populating one of the data criteria's but im not sure how to make this work for multiple values across multiple cells. The 7 prices are all located in cells along row 3.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Screenshot would really help visualise what you're on about.

Answer (score 0):

You can string the `IF` statements together like so:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D7), "JP-5", 
IF(D7=criteria, x,
IF(D7=criteria1, y,
...))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of prices. For example, use cells A1:B7 for this, column a will be the inputs (products?) and column b will be the  prices. Then you can find the price of a given product in cell D7 like this:

`=vlookup(d7, A1:B7 , 2, false)`.

It will find the corresponding product in column a and return the price in column b (the second column).

Be careful to spell things consistently though. If it can’t find what you tell it to find (even because of spelling) it will through an error.